# SQL : how to find max time where its type is varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I have a question in which I have to find details of the store from a  store table which opens the latest during the weekend. in store table, I have an attribute named weekendHours with the type varchar2 and the example is : (10:00 am - 5:00pm). 
I tried 
To_char( S.WeekendHours=max(S.WeekendHours );
but it does not work!!
how can I do that?

Comment: You need to provide more examples of what the data looks like and what you are trying to accomplish.  What does "max time" mean in this context?  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Tagged with `oracle` because of mentioning `varchar2`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract the opening and closing times, and then manipulate those as needed:

```
SELECT s.*,
       TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(s.weekend_hours, '[0-9]+:*[0-9]* *(am|pm)*', 1, 1)) AS OPENING_HOUR_STRING,
       TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(s.weekend_hours, '[0-9]+:*[0-9]* *(am|pm)*', 1, 2)) AS CLOSING_HOUR_STRING
      FROM STORE s
```

Once you have the basic information above, you can manipulate it to obtain the opening and closing times as dates, then use MAX on the appropriate field:

```
WITH cteSTORE_STRING_VALUES AS
       (SELECT s.*,
               TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(s.weekend_hours, '[0-9]+:*[0-9]* *(am|pm)*', 1, 1)) AS OPENING_HOUR_STRING,
               TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(s.weekend_hours, '[0-9]+:*[0-9]* *(am|pm)*', 1, 2)) AS CLOSING_HOUR_STRING
          FROM STORE s),
     cteALL_STORE_VALUES AS
       (SELECT s.*,
               CASE
                 WHEN LENGTH(OPENING_HOUR_STRING) < 4 THEN LPAD(OPENING_HOUR_STRING, 4, '0')
                 ELSE OPENING_HOUR_STRING
               END AS PADDED_OPENING_STRING,
               CASE
                 WHEN LENGTH(CLOSING_HOUR_STRING) < 4 THEN LPAD(CLOSING_HOUR_STRING, 4, '0')
                 ELSE CLOSING_HOUR_STRING
               END AS PADDED_CLOSING_STRING
          FROM cteSTORE_STRING_VALUES s),
     cteSTORES_WITH_HOURS AS
       (SELECT a.*,
               CASE
                 WHEN UPPER(SUBSTR(a.OPENING_HOUR_STRING, -3)) IN (' AM', ' PM') THEN
                   TO_DATE(a.OPENING_HOUR_STRING, 'HH:MI AM')
                 WHEN UPPER(SUBSTR(a.OPENING_HOUR_STRING, -2)) IN ('AM', 'PM') THEN
                   TO_DATE(a.OPENING_HOUR_STRING, 'HH:MIAM')
                 WHEN INSTR(a.OPENING_HOUR_STRING, ':') > 0 THEN
                   TO_DATE(a.OPENING_HOUR_STRING, 'HH24:MI')
                 ELSE
                   TO_DATE(a.PADDED_OPENING_STRING, 'HH24MI')
               END AS OPENING_HOURS,
               CASE
                 WHEN UPPER(SUBSTR(a.CLOSING_HOUR_STRING, -3)) IN (' AM', ' PM') THEN
                   TO_DATE(a.CLOSING_HOUR_STRING, 'HH:MI AM')
                 WHEN UPPER(SUBSTR(a.CLOSING_HOUR_STRING, -2)) IN ('AM', 'PM') THEN
                   TO_DATE(a.CLOSING_HOUR_STRING, 'HH:MIAM')
                 WHEN INSTR(a.CLOSING_HOUR_STRING, ':') > 0 THEN
                   TO_DATE(a.CLOSING_HOUR_STRING, 'HH24:MI')
                 ELSE
                   TO_DATE(a.PADDED_CLOSING_STRING, 'HH24MI')
               END AS CLOSING_HOURS
          FROM cteALL_STORE_VALUES a)
SELECT *
  FROM cteSTORES_WITH_HOURS
  WHERE OPENING_HOURS = (SELECT MAX(OPENING_HOURS)
                           FROM cteSTORES_WITH_HOURS);
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d2e8c/25)

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the store that opens the latest, then you conceivably could do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.weekendhours desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

However, with your time format, that will not work, because 2:00 a.m. would be after 1:00 p.m.

So, you need to convert the range to a time.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
order by cast(substring(t.weekendhours, 1, 8) as time) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Of course, these queries use common methods across many databases.  The logic might work on your database, but the syntax could be different.

Note:  All of this is because the column `weekendhours` is broken.  It should be in two columns, the `weekend_opentime` and `weekend_closetime`.  Then the query would be trivial.

Comment: @pariaashtianipour . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions, with sample data, desired results, your attempt to answer, and a proper database tag.